# Poses are Applied to my Dopesheet Automatically

Tags: animation, pose-mode, dopesheet

I'm trying to match animations to an idle state. So any animation that ends with standing I want the ending to match the idle animation. Likewise with any animation that starts with standing.

When I add poses to the library the poses are automatically applied to my dopesheet.
The first pose is set as frame 0.
The second as pose 1.

How do I make a pose library that I can copy keyframes from to do the matching I'm trying to acomplish?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So... you have to make pose library that is separate from your animation apparently.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the old pose library, which is just there for backward compatibility. Use the new pose library from the Asset Broeser and the Action editor's N-panel for a more modern approach.

See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/animation/armatures/posing/editing/pose_library.html for more info.